# In iOS , Is it possible to place Different sections of the Same UITableView into different Places on the View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to have different sections of same TableView into different positions on the view controller, but no luck..

I want to put 2 sections of the same table view away from each other via some CGcoordinates or something.

so Is it possible to moveor place 2 sections of the same tableview into different position on the view?

In simple terms: Is it possible to add sections side by side
Thanks In Advance

Comment: No. A `UITableView` is a single view. It can't be split into multiple views.

Comment: @rmaddy Is is possible to have sections as vertically aligned instead of horizontally aligned..?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display two sections side-by-side (left/right)?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes exactly , i want to display 2 section side by side

Comment: Not with `UITableView`. Perhaps a `UICollectionView` is what you want.

Comment: How about rotating the tableview by 90 degree, there by u can get side by side sections

Comment: Is it possible to add sections side by side

Comment: @shan A sec, let me give it a try

Comment: @shan will not work , both the sections will turn 90 deg including the text

Comment: @shan no it is even bad, cell will turn but will not be aligned vertically

Comment: @yashaskumar it is working fine rotate the cell by -90 degree not 90 degree

Comment: @shan this is the code i am using: cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(M_PI/2));

Comment: use this  Cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * -90); both are same

Comment: Just use two separate table views.  If you need them to scroll in sync, [check this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9879138/77567) for example.

Comment: @robmayoff My real Intention was to drag and drop cells from one table  to another table, but i couldn't figure out a easy and efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @robmayoff But drag and drop between sections in same table view is very easy to do. Is there any way to achieve drag and drop between tables very easily?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-drag-and-drop-between-uitableviews/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the code this is one way u can do it, by looking at others comment u can also do it by using collection view my solution would be like below,

just an example just try it hope this helps u :)

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * 90);
    self.tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableview.frame.size.height, self.tableview.frame.size.width);//inter change the width and height a

  }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return 2;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
     return 10;
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
     if(Cell == nil)
     {
        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
     }
     Cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * -90);

     Cell.textLabel.text = @"Happy coding";
     return Cell;
 }

  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    return 320.0f; //width
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @shan for the code..

I wanted my view to be something like this.
section1 section2
data     data
but i could'nt accomplish that...

Comment: my reputation is very low to post the image so sry for that

Comment: i could't get can u update your question, show it in your question

Comment: if u are using dropbox then upload it there and post the link

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/n1tjptk7d/ try this, in the image instead of 2 tables , it should be 2 sections like that

Comment: u can use 2 tableviews rite

Comment: well, i think now that there is no way to do side-by-side using section based on the discussion i had with u and others, so i will be using 2 table views then