# How to scroll two UITableViews Simultaneously?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I have two UITableViews, one for date and another for text.
But they are both scrollable indecently, I want them to scroll together.
I'll attach a photo of my app.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe be limplementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods of the `UITableView` and being its delegate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918481/making-two-uiscrollviews-follow-each-others-scrolling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879138/syncing-the-scroll-position-of-multiple-uitableview-instances etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wonders, I got to solve this by simply using one `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`.